# Column Firstname cannot be null

Tags: c#, mysql

it Below is my code.. I have tried several answers on the platform but its still giving me the same error.. Someone please help me out!!!! Thanks in advance!

```
public bool saveRecord(string Firstname,string Lastname,string Username,string Password,string Emailadress)
{
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=8889;Database=SSC;Uid=root;Password=root"))
    {
        try
        {
            string Sql_Query = "INSERT INTO administrator (Firstname,Lastname,Username,Password,EmailAdress)VALUES(@Firstname,@Lastname,@Username,@Password,@EmailAdress);";
            connection.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(Sql_Query, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", Firstname);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", Lastname);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAdress", Emailadress);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Testing class.....

```
Models model = new Models();
if (model.saveRecord(TbFisrtname.Text, TbLastname.Text,TbUsername.Text,TbPassword.Text,TbAddress.Text) == true)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
}
```

Comment: Is the FirstName column of table Administrator set as not null?  Is `TbFirstname.Text` null?

Comment: If `null` is acceptable, insert `DbNull.Value` instead.

Comment: Please my answer as correct, if you determine it to be correct.  Thank you

Comment: @Silvermind , I tried using the DbNull.value but still error occurring . Thanks for the help tho

Comment: @DavidPine, That also couldn't work out please!

Comment: @DavidPine , Yes , I am using windows forms

Answer (score 0):

This is an indication the the `FirstName` parameter variable is null as it is passed into the method.  I suggest validating your arguments as such:

```
    public bool saveRecord(string Firstname,string Lastname,string Username,string Password,string Emailadress)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstName))
           throw new ArgumentException(FirstName, "FirstName cannot be null");
        // Do the same for the other args...

        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=8889;Database=SSC;Uid=root;Password=root"))
        {
            try
            {
                string Sql_Query = "INSERT INTO administrator (Firstname,Lastname,Username,Password,EmailAdress)VALUES(@Firstname,@Lastname,@Username,@Password,@EmailAdress);";
                connection.Open();    

                using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(Sql_Query, connection))
                {

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", Firstname);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", Lastname);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAdress", Emailadress);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Inserted");

                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Is there any other way I could perform a successful CRUD operation for my project ??  I have been stuck for days please!

Comment: There are countless ways that you can perform CRUD operations.  You are not providing enough information for us to help you though.  Are you using WinForms?